# Optimizing my XSLT selector

Tags: xml, xslt, orbeon

i'm using the orbeon form builder and want to add a value to the class attribute of some elements. To do this i'm using the code below, but i would like to know how to optimize this code. It must be possible to combine each 2 template tags, because the only difference is that is case 1 i set the class attribute to a value, and in case 2 i add some text to the class attribute..

Maybe it is even possible to combine all this code into 1 template tag? (one with multiple selectors (match) and with the set/append class attribute?

```
Case 1: 
   <xsl:template match="xforms:input/@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="."/> 
        <xsl:attribute name="class">tsbinput-<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>      
   </xsl:template> 
Case 2:
   <xsl:template match="xforms:input/@class">
        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="."/> tsbinput-<xsl:value-of select="../@id"/></xsl:attribute>      
   </xsl:template>

Case 1:    
    <xsl:template match="fr:number/@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="."/> 
        <xsl:attribute name="class">tsbinput-<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>      
   </xsl:template> 
Case 2:
   <xsl:template match="fr:number/@class">
        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="."/> tsbinput-<xsl:value-of select="../@id"/></xsl:attribute>      
   </xsl:template>

Case 1:
   <xsl:template match="fr:textcount/@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="."/> 
        <xsl:attribute name="class">tsbinput-<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>      
   </xsl:template> 
Case 2:
   <xsl:template match="fr:textcount/@class">
        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="."/> tsbinput-<xsl:value-of select="../@id"/></xsl:attribute>      
   </xsl:template>
```

Please help me. 
Thanks, Nico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these templates can be simplified a bit.  You can replace the six you have with these three:

```
  <xsl:template match="@id[parent::xforms:input or 
                           parent::fr:number or 
                           parent::fr:textcount]">
    <xsl:copy />
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../@class, ' tsbinput-', .)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@class[../@id]
                             [parent::xforms:input or 
                              parent::fr:number or 
                              parent::fr:textcount]" />

  <xsl:template match="@class[not(../@id)]
                             [parent::xforms:input or 
                              parent::fr:number or 
                              parent::fr:textcount]">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>
```

If it can be guaranteed that the `xforms:input`, `fr:number`, and `fr:textcount` will **always** have an `@id` attribute, then you can delete the third template.

One way to further simplify this is to add this key to the top of your XSLT:

```
  <xsl:key name="kAdjustClass" 
           match="xforms:input | fr:number | fr:textcount"
           use="name()" />
```

And then you could change the above three templates to this:

```
  <xsl:template match="@id[key('kAdjustClass', name(..))]">
    <xsl:copy />
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../@class, ' tsbinput-', .)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@class[../@id][key('kAdjustClass', name(..))]" />
  <xsl:template match="@class[not(../@id)][key('kAdjustClass', name(..))]">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you maybe tell me how to also add the id of the parent fr:section? Something like: ?
    `<xsl:template match="@id[key('kAdjustClass', name(..))]">
      <xsl:copy />
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(../@class, ' 123 ', parent::fr:section/@id, '-tsb2input-', .)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

    </xsl:template>`

Comment: Instead of `parent::fr:section/@id`, please try: `../parent::fr:section/@id` or `ancestor::fr:section/@id`.